# DELETE with wrong header returns 404 although entity is existing

Tags: fiware-orion

We accidentaly inserted entities into orion using the wrong header (typo)
`fiware-service-path` instead of the correct one `fiware-servicepath` (withouht the last hyphen) and now I am unable to delete the entities. I also tested the [python script delete_entities_by_query](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/scripts/utils/delete_entities_by_query.py) directly on the server without any authorization and that also returns a list of entities.

```
There are 61 entities
There are 0 pages of 500 entities (and a final page of 61 entities)
```

Trying to delete always result ins a 404 although the following query returns entites:

```
--header 'fiware-service: something' \
--header 'fiware-service-path: asdf' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN'
```

e.g. returns an entity 
`id:urn:ngsi-ld:6c99ecaa-5cee-4f27-b936-3ccbe8c42d66`

DELETE:

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'https://<orion>/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:6c99ecaa-5cee-4f27-b936-3ccbe8c42d66' \
--header 'fiware-service: something' \
--header 'fiware-service-path: asdf' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN'
```

returns a 404.
`{"error":"NotFound","description":"The requested entity has not been found. Check type and id"}`

Answer (score 0):

The right header to specify service path in Orion is `fiware-servicepath` (not `fiware-service-path`). Maybe that is the cause of the problem (the `fiware-service-path` header is ignored by Orion, so it assumes `fiware-servicepath: /` implicitly, the entity is not found there and 404 is returned).

Note also that the syntax for service path mandates to start with `/`. Thus, `asdf` is not a valid service path, while `/asdf` is.

Comment: Well, inserting seems to have worked, so the header did not get ignored and maybe interpreted as custom header. When I remove the header I don't see any entity. To me it appears that the DELETE ignores the header in contrast to insert or getting all data. v2/types also sucessfully lists the types wtih the wrong header